# htaccess rewrite rule to remove parameters from wildcard-URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

The user types the following into the browser

**example:**

```
/dog/cat/whale/
or
/dog/cat/whale/pinguin/
or
/dog/cat/whale?test=test
or
/dog/cat/whale/pinguin?test=test&chars=abc
```

for this specific path the user should be redirected to an url without parameters

**example:**

```
https://mylittleshop.com/animals
```

**My solution:**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dog/cat/whale.*$    https://mylittleshop.com/animals?
```

Working, but the target-path contains an undesirable questionmark.

What can i do to remove the questionmark from url?

Answer (score 0):

Try the QSD flag (only available with Apache 2.4+) :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dog/cat/whale.*$    https://mylittleshop.com/animals [QSD]
```

Prior to Apache 2.4, you can try

```
RewriteRule ^/dog/cat/whale.*$    https://mylittleshop.com/animals? [R=301]
```

The question mark at the end should reset the query string and don't be displayed in the URL

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tested your suggestion but the version of apache is < 2.4. Do you know solution for Apache 2.2 or 2.3?